# Using Scrapy to download images from a google search

Tags: image, url, search, scrapy

I am trying to download google images for a particular search.

Currently, if i have the url, my code will download the first 10 images.

However, my question is: How would i get the url for a particular search on google?

When i look at the url for any search on google, it looks very complicated and it seems hard to understand how the url was created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The &q= part of the url is the actual search string. Note that some characters are converted such as space becoming plus etc.

Easy enough to fake by doing https://www.google.com/search?q=a+search

For image search [https://www.google.com/search?q=a+search&tbm=isch](https://www.google.com/search?q=a+search)

Comment: How would i go to the images page though?

Comment: &tbm=isch all together: https://www.google.com/search?q=a+search&tbm=isch but for parsing search query out it doesn't matter does it?

Comment: well. i am downloading the images from the image page so the second link really helps. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you wanted the search query _from_ a url, not the other way around xD

Answer (score 3):

```
http://www.google.com/m/search?q=hello&site=images
```

This URL pulls up the mobile website, which is static and is easier to harvest images off of. All parts of the query are self-explanatory